# What is the value of a creature's STR, DEX, or WIL if the attribute is not listed?

Tags: attributes, cairn

[Cairn bestiary](https://cairnrpg.com/resources/monsters/dog-wild/):

> **Dog, Wild**
> 3 HP, 12 DEX, bite (d6)

Do I roll to create STR and WIL per-pup?

Are the stats 10 (average)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Into The Odd and its derivatives, if the stat is not listed, it is always 10. I am (slowly) rewriting the bestiary to add in every single missing stat, to make it more usable.

Answer (score 4):

## Unlisted attributes are always 10.

[Yochai Gal](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/34334/yochai-gal), Cairn author, [responded](https://discord.com/channels/1014336546746421259/1016516043151249478/1136398028257906820) in the [official Cairn discord](https://cairnrpg.com/discord-server/):

> It is NOT in [the rules, but] it is a common [Into the Odd](https://freeleaguepublishing.com/en/games/into-the-odd/) thing.

Comment: Ya this makes the most sense. If it's not listed then there is some default baseline it's assuming. What would a stat's default be other than 10 right?

Comment: @Ben My Warden had thought he needed to roll 3d6 for each missing stat...

Comment: Roll 3d6 for each missing stat doesn't sound bad - maybe one dog is a lot stronger than another. But it slows down gameplay.